# int and float division giving 0 as output

Tags: c, gcc

```
int main(void)
{
  int x;
  float y;

  x=10;
  y=4.0;

  printf("%d\n",x/y);

  return 0;
}
```

I compiled this code using a gcc compiler and when run I get 0 as output.
Why is this code giving output as 0 instead of 2?

Comment: it's undefined behaviour

Comment: `-Wall` is your friend - format `%d` expects type `int`, but argument 2 has type `double`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of **x/y** is a `float` and is transferred to `printf()` as such.
However, you told `printf()` using `%d` to assume the input is an `int`.
There is no type-checking or automatic type-conversion in this case. `printf()` will just execute what you asked. This, by sheer accident, results in a **0** being printed.

You should have specified `%d` in the format string and cast the result of the division to `int`.

```
printf("%d\n", (int)(x/y) );
```

Or you could have used `%f`, but then you would have gotten **2.5** as output. (You might want to take a look at the floor() function too.)

Comment: 4 * 2.5 = 10, 4 + 4 + (.5*4) = 10, 8 + (4/2) = 10, 8 + 2 = 10

Answer (score 7):

IT's not the division, it's the print format.

Change:

```
printf("%d\n",x/y);
```

to:

```
printf("%f\n",x/y);
```

Comment: %f gives 2.5. The x gets implicitly cast to float before the division.

Comment: Yes `%f` gives correct o/p as _2.500000_ but my question is using `%d` it should give 2 as o/p but why  is it giving _0_?

Comment: @Neo_Sci a) because using the wrong format specifier invokes undefined behaviour, so anything could happen. b) because the four bytes (probably) of the bit representation of the `double` 2.5 that are read to print an `int` are all 0. But that's incidental because of a).